# Are password-protected notes encrypted?

Tags: security, password, encryption, notes.app

I can't find anything about encryption on Apple's sites, but are password-protected notes using E2E encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Secure Notes are encrypted with [Triple DES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.csfb400/tdes1.htm), and are kept in the device keychain.